# CSS: How to set procentual width using display:flex?

Tags: html, css, width, flexbox

I have a requirement where I need to align content vertically within some divs. Flex-box would provide exactly what I need in an elegant way.

But I can't fully figure out whats the best way of setting the width of the flex-items is. If i use `flex: 50%`, the items grow with their content (which is not what I want). Also, I am not able to use `overflow: hidden` (because of the content within the divs).

Is it viable to set the **width** by using the good old width-property (this would work)? In other words: display: flex without flex: xx?

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  width: 200px;
}

.left {
  display: flex;
  flex: 50%;
  background-color: green;
  /* overflow: hidden; *//* can't use that */
}

.right {
  display: flex;
  flex: 50%;
  background-color: red;
  /* overflow: hidden; *//* can't use that */
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="left">BigBigBigBigBig</div>
  <div class="right">Small</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `flex: 0 0 50%` so [`flex-grow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-grow) will be set to **0** and it won't grow over `50%`.

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  width: 200px;
  align-items: center;
}

.left {
  flex: 0 0 50%;
  background-color: green;
  word-break: break-all;
}

.right {
  flex: 0 0 50%;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="left">BigBigBsdfsdfigBigBigsdfsdf</div>
  <div class="right">Small</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! My snippet was not precice enough - sorry for that. I made some changes: https://jsfiddle.net/p43madua/6/. Would you mind to take a look?

Comment: I see! Very good. Can you make an assumption if this is cleaner than just setting the good old width? Also, do you know why is the behavior changing if I have a min-width? Is this spec?

Answer (score 0):

Does the fiddle supplied answer your question, just not too sure this is what you are after.

Comment: Thanks. It's 50/50 now. But I need text-overflow: ellipsis to work. Are you aware how to do it?

Comment: This should do it:-`.textToEllipsis {
  width: 250px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
},